How to yarn start nextjs application on specific port with pm2?
How to yarn start nextjs application on specific port with pm2 process manager?
I googled for answer and found wrong suggestions
On production server I want to configure fail-over load balancer to enable high loads and deployment without Bad Gateway error.

Finally found command to start yarn start in pm2 on port 3003.
"i_frontend_3" is process name for pm2.
On Ubuntu 22.04, in project directory, do:
pm2 start yarn --name i_frontend_3 -- start -- -p 3003
In other operating systems, people on internet suggest to specify interpreter bash:
pm2 start yarn --name i_frontend_3 --interpreter bash -- start -- -p 3003
